# Wordpress Search - Reject partial matches

Tags: search

I'm currently looking into a solution for a project i'm working on where I would use the basic WP Search (the S attribute to a WP_Query) but it would need to only return full word matches (and reject partial-word matches)

Like if I search for Phone, I want to return only Phones and not Cellphones or iPhones.

Is there a way to ask WP to only return full word matches?

Comment: such a change would certainly require SQL adjustments, WP search isn't very sophisticated. Have you considered using something dedicated to search such as Elastic or Algolia?

Comment: Yeah, and I would not want to rock the boat that hard on this site. Search plugins would take over the whole search process and I need it only on one element in particular. Guess I'll filter my research to change the SQL if there is no easy way.

Comment: @Fredy31 WordPress always uses `LIKE '%<keyword>%'` when searching (except when the `exact` parameter is true), so for now, without using a 3rd-party plugin, you can use the [`posts_search` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_search/) which gives you full control over the search SQL, so you can modify it or completely reconstruct it based on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('posts_search', 'my_search_is_exact', 20, 2);

function my_search_is_exact($search, $wp_query){

     global $wpdb;

     if(empty($search))
         return $search;

     $q = $wp_query->query_vars;
     $n = !empty($q['exact']) ? '' : '%';

     $search = $searchand = '';

     foreach((array)$q['search_terms'] as $term) :

         $term = esc_sql(like_escape($term));

         $search.= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title REGEXP '[[:<:]]{$term}[[:>:]]') OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content REGEXP '[[:<:]]{$term}[[:>:]]')";

         $searchand = ' AND ';

     endforeach;

     if(!empty($search)) :
         $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
         if(!is_user_logged_in())
             $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
     endif;

     return $search;

}
```